# Proving $g(\chi\rho)^6=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p(\overline{\chi(2)J(\chi,\rho)})^4$, from Ireland and Rosen.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, characters

Suppose $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, $\chi$ is a cubic character, and $\rho$ is the quadratic character on $F_p$.

> If $\chi\rho$ is a character of order $6$, why does the Guass sum $g(\chi\rho)^6=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p\bar{\pi}^4$ where $\pi=\chi(2)J(\chi,\rho)$.

I derived a few formulas, $g(\chi)^3=p\pi$, and if $\chi^2\neq\epsilon$, then $g(\chi)^2=\chi(2)^{-2}J(\chi,\rho)g(\chi^2)$ and $J(\chi,\chi)=\chi(2)^{-2}J(\chi,\rho)$. These are all previous exercises in the book.

Using the last equation, I find
$$
\pi=\chi(2)\chi(2)^2J(\chi,\chi)=J(\chi,\chi).
$$
Also, since $\chi$ is a cubic character, $g(\chi)^3=pJ(\chi,\chi)$.

Since $\chi\rho$ is nontrivial, 
$$
g(\chi\rho)=\frac{g(\chi)g(\rho)}{J(\chi,\rho)}=\frac{g(\chi)g(\rho)}{\chi(2)^2J(\chi,\chi)}
$$
so
$$
g(\chi\rho)^6=\frac{g(\chi)^6g(\rho)^6}{\chi(2)^{12}J(\chi,\chi)^6}=\frac{p^2J(\chi,\chi)^2g(\rho)^6}{J(\chi,\chi)^6}=\frac{p^2g(\rho)^6}{\pi^4}.
$$
This looks kind of close since there is at least a power of $\pi^4$. I know that $g(\rho)^6=\pm p^3$, with sign depending on the value of $p\mod 4$, which is unknown. I also know that $\rho(-1)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$, which is curious since it shows up in the equation. How can the equality be derived? Thanks.

Source: I&R #8.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got it. The sign in $g(\rho)^6=\pm p^3$ is, as you know, $+$ if $p\equiv1\pmod4$, and $-$ if $p\equiv-1\pmod4$, which is to say, $$g(\rho)^6=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p^3.$$ I think the only thing you're missing is $\pi\overline{\pi}=p$, because that gives you $${p^2g(\rho)^6\over\pi^4}={p^2(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p^3\over\pi^4}=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p\overline{\pi}^4,$$ as desired.

So: can you get $p=\pi\overline{\pi}$?

Comment: Dear Gerry, thank you very much! I was able to finish with your guidance.

Comment: Hello! I know I’m late but how were you able to conclude that $g(\rho)^6= (-1)^{p-1/2}p^3$?

Comment: @Mashed, that follows from $g(p)^6=\pm p^3$, from taking the plus sign if $p\equiv1\bmod4$ and the minus sign if $p\equiv-1\bmod4$, and from $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ being $+1$ if $p\equiv1\bmod4$ and $-1$ if $p\equiv-1\bmod4$.

Comment: How did we arrive at $g(\rho)^6=\pm p^3$? I’m assuming we need to show that $g(\rho)^2=\pm p$, but how do we show this?

Comment: Please make up your mind as to exactly where you get lost in the argument. I got $g(\rho)^6=\pm p^3$ from where Noomi wrote, "I know $g(\rho)^6=\pm p^3$", and I just took Noomi's word for it. It has been a while since I've looked at all this, but if I'm not mistaken, then $g(\rho)$ is just the quadratic Gauss sum, and is $\sqrt p$ if $p\equiv1\bmod4$, $i\sqrt p$ if $p\equiv-1\bmod4$. Surely that's proved in Ireland and Rosen. But if you want a proof, I suggest you post a new question (after first checking to see whether the question has already been asked and answered on this site).

Comment: @Mashed, see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775320/quadratic-gauss-sum

Comment: @Mashed, making progress?

Comment: Hi @GerryMyerson, sorry for the very late reply. But if I remember correctly, the proof is actually quite simple. I just used the fact that $|g(\rho)|^2=p$ and I was able to prove it from there. Thanks for the help.